# Connect to SQL Server. Error 26 : the type initializer threw an exception: error locating server instance specified

Tags: networking, firewall, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2014 Express installation. It is configured for

- Remote connections
- TCP is activated
- mixed mode Authentications are allowed and
- the server firewall is deactivated

My program connects to that server from my machine which works fine. My connection string is

```
user id=user1;password=pass;server=192.168.0.1;Trusted_Connection=no;database=myDb;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

But if I want to execute my program from another machine I get the error message:

> Connect to SQL Server. Error 26: the type initializer threw an exception. error locating server instance specified

Since it works from my client it can't be a server configuration issue.

I already opened the TCP port 1433 and UDP port 1434 on the problematic client, but it still does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: what type of connection are you using? ODBC, OleDB, SQLServer native...? is the data source parameter using a short server name, or a fully qualified one? can you ping and NSLookup the server server from that client? are named pipes enabled? did you restart the service after allowing TCP and named pipes?

Comment: I added the connection string to my question. I use a C# app with a native SQL driver I guess. TCP and named pipes are activated currently. I restarted the service and even the server.

Comment: Also, note that opening the firewall ports on the client will have no effect, and it is unlikely that the server firewall is blocking. Because your message indicates that the server INSTANCE could not be found, I am wondering about your database= parameter. do you have multiple instances on that server? is this a named or default instance? what happens if you drop that clause?

Comment: The server firewall is turned off. I have a default instance called MSSQLSERVER. I also tried adding it to the connection string, but with the same result

Comment: well, with a default instance, you just don't name it. That said, your connection string looks odd, lacking as it does 'Data Source=', 'Initial Catalog=', etc. perhaps my experience with connection strings hasn't caught up to the latest line of SQLServer products. That said, try: `Data Source="192.168.0.1"; Initial Catalog="MyDB"; user id="user1"; password="pass"; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;`

Comment: Thanks for the support. But the error is exactly the same with the other connection string.